# what does "You had much better dance" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

“Come, Darcy,” said he, “I must have you dance. I hate to see you standing about by yourself in this stupid manner. You had much better dance.”

Comment: *had better* a one of the ways to give an advice. *Much* here probably only for emphasis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Had better" is an archaism which survives as an idiom. "You had better ..." (still) means "It would be better if you ... "

In current English, since it is an idiom, it doesn't really work to put extra words in; but in Austen's day its grammar was still current, and so it was a living expression, and could be varied, as here, by inserting an intensifier "You had much better " = "It would be much better if you ... ".

Comment: Hmmm... I'm familiar with the issue of fixedness in idioms, but this seems to "really" work, in Austen's time or yours and mine. Or am I out to freaking lunch?

Comment: I find it a bit odd. YMMV.

Comment: "Had better" also survives as the lead-in to a threat:  *You had better do it if you know what's good for you*.

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat older way of saying what in modern English would be said as : It's better if you dance.